# Mysql Multiple count and select

Tags: mysql, sql

hi guys i am trying to count the specific items for specific ID

db result

```
name                      remarks
joseph greggory           On time
joseph greggory           On time
lara joy                  On time
lara joy                  Absent
Mark Joben                On time
Mark Joben                Absent
Isnaira Lyn               Absent
Isnaira Lyn               Absent
```

result should be

```
name                  On time         Late       Absent
joseph Greggory         2              0            0
Lara Joy                1              0            1
Mark Joben              1              0            1
Isnaira Lyn             0              0            2
```

thank you guys in advance

Comment: There's not nearly enough information provided here to answer this. What query? What's the table structure? If you can edit your question for clarity please flag it for moderator review.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN remarks = 'On time' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `On time`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN remarks = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Late`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN remarks = 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `Absent`  
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/252d4/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
select name,
       count(case when remarks = 'On time' then 1 end) "On time",
       count(case when remarks = 'Late' then 1 end) "Remarks",
       count(case when remarks = 'Absent' then 1 end) "Absent"
from table1
group by name;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE OUTPUT](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f238a/9/0)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT  name,
        COUNT(IF(remarks = 'On time', 1, NULL)) `On time`,
        COUNT(IF(remarks = 'Late', 1, NULL)) `Late`,
        COUNT(IF(remarks = 'Absent', 1, NULL)) `Absent`  
FROM    tbl
GROUP   BY name
```